# Find compression codec used for an hadoop file

Tags: hadoop, compression, avro, parquet, sequencefile

Given a compressed file, written on hadoop platform, in one of the following formats:

- Avro
- Parquet
- SequenceFile

How can I find the compression codec used? Assuming that one of the following compression codecs is used (and there is no file extension in the file name):

- Snappy
- Gzip (not supported on Avro)
- Deflate (not supported on Parquet)

Comment: You could try a hex editor or otherwise inspecting raw bytes... Avro and Parquet at least have a well defined binary format and will list their internal compression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java implementation of Parquet includes the `parquet-tools` utility, providing several commands. See its [documentation page](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools) for building and getting started. The more detailed descriptions of the individual commands are printed by `parquet-tools` itself. The command you are looking for is `meta`. This will show all kinds of metadata, including compressions. You can find an example output [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/cdh_ig_parquet.html#parquet_files), showing SNAPPY compression.

Please note that the compression algorithm does not have to be the same across the whole file. Different column chunks can use different compressions, therefore there is no single field for the compression codec, but one for each column chunk instead. (A column chunk is the part of a column that belong to one row group.) In practice, however, you will probably find the same compression codec being used for all column chunks.

A similar utility exists for Avro, called `avro-tool`. I'm not that familiar with it, but it [has](https://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/03/17/reading-and-writing-avro-files-from-the-command-line/#tools-included-in-avro-tools) a `getmeta` command which should show you the compression codec used.

Comment: This seems to be the right approach, I will accept the answer. Is there any tool like avro-tools or parquet-tools for SequenceFile to extract metadata informations?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not aware of any command-line tool to inspect the metadata of sequencefiles. The API allows querying that though, but that requires writing a small Java program.

Comment: Yes. It seems also sufficient to show the first 100 bytes of a sequencefile, like: <br>
hdfs dfs -cat /path/to/file | head -c 100 <br>
SEQ!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritableorders'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec <br>
The codec should be readable in the output.

Comment: Nice! Good to know.